# ansible conditional "when" not works with role

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, yaml, ansible

in my playbook i have a condition to execute role according the version in the playbook command but it executes the two roles when i add version=8

```
- hosts: tomcat-servers
  remote_user: root
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  pre_tasks:
    - debug: var=version
  roles:
    - { role: tomcat7, when: version == '7' }
    - { role: tomcat8, when: version == '8' }
```

the command :

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml --extra-vars "version=8"
```

for the debug output :

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.139.129] => {
    "version": "8"
}
```

any help?

ansible 2.1.0.0

Comment: thats weird, i've tried locally and its all right. Can you add a `pre_tasks` to debug print the version value ?

Comment: i'm beginner in ansible can you show me how can i do it please

Comment: search for `pre_tasks` in the [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#roles) pages for an example. And you want to do something like `- debug: var=version` ([debug docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/debug_module.html#examples))

Comment: thanks, i updated my question with the output console

Comment: Can you also paste sample output ? (truncate the roles steps if they are too many)

Comment: find it in this page : http://pastebin.com/aA8G13kP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(sample output from pastebin above)

```
ubuntu# ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml --extra-vars "version=8"

PLAY [tomcat-servers] **********************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.139.129]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.139.129] => {
    "version": "8"
}

TASK [tomcat7 : Install Java 1.8] **********************************************
skipping: [192.168.139.129]

[..]
TASK [tomcat8 : Install Java 1.8] **********************************************
ok: [192.168.139.129]

TASK [tomcat8 : add group "tomcat"] ********************************************
ok: [192.168.139.129]

[...]
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.139.129            : ok=14   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

You can see from the tasks above that there are two types:

1. skipping: [192.168.139.129]
2. ok: [192.168.139.129]

This is ansibles way notifying you if a task is executed or not.

So when you specify `version=8`, you are only executing tomcat8 role, but tomcat7 tasks are displayed as `skipped`.

If you enable colours, you can see the different colours for the tasks (skipped = blue, changed = yellow)

[image]

Comment: to disable displaying the skipped tasks, see [this](http://serverfault.com/a/807152/290351)